# How to properly use hg share extension?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

Say I have cloned a repo to a directory called `~/trunk` and I want to share a branch named my-new-branch to the directory `~/my-new-branch`. How would I do that with the `hg share` extension?

This is what I've been doing:

```
cd ~
hg share trunk my-new-branch
```

But then when I `cd` into the new directory I have to hg up to the branch?

Confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO *`share` is a very useful command* which has some great advantages over `clone` in some cases. But I think it is unfortunately overlooked in many instances.

[What `share` does](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShareExtension) is to re-use the 'store' of Mercurial version control information between more than one local repository. (It has nothing directly to do with branching.)

<sub>The 'store' is a bunch of files which represents all the history Mercurial saves for you. You don't interact with it directly. Its a black box 99.99% of the time.</sub>

`share` differs from the more commonly-used `clone` command in that `clone` would copy the information store, taking longer to run and using potentially a lot more disk space.

The "side effect" of using `share` rather than `clone` is that you will instantly see all the same commits in *every* `shared` repository. It is as if push/pull were to happen automatically among all the `shared` repos. This would not be true with `clone`, you'd have to explicitly push/pull first. This is quite useful but something to be mindful of in your workflow because it may surprise you the first time you use it if you are only used to `clone`.

---

If you want to work in multiple branches (named or unnamed) of your project simultaneously,
either `clone` or `share` will work fine. Once you have created the second repository, yes you need to `update` it to whatever changeset you want to begin working on.

Concrete example using `share`:

```
hg clone path\to\source\repo working1   # Create local repo working1 cloned from somewhere
cd working1
hg up branchname1  

cd ..

hg share working1 working2  # shares the 'store' already used for working1 with working2
cd working2
hg up branchname2  # some other branch or point to start working from
```

As soon as you commit something in `working1` that commit will be visible in the history of `working2`. But since they are not on the same branch this has no real immediate effect on `working2`.

`working2` will retain `path\to\source\repo` as its default push/pull location, just like `working1`.

---

My own practice has been to create numerous locally `shared` repositories (quick, easy, saves space) and work in various branches. Often I'll even have a few of them on the same named branch but set to different points in history, for various reasons. I no longer find much need to actually `clone` locally (on the same PC).

---

A caveat -- I would avoid using share across a network connection - like to a repo on a network drive. I think that could suffer some performance or even reliability issues. In fact, I wouldn't work off a network drive with a Mercurial repo (if avoidable) in any circumstance. Cloning locally would be safer.

Secondly -- [I would read the docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShareExtension#General_caveats), there are a few weird scenarios you might encounter; but I think these are not likely just based on my own experience.

---

Final note: although share is implemented as an "extension" to Mercurial, it has been effectively a part of it since forever. So there is nothing new or experimental about it, don't let the "extension" deal put you off.

Comment: @jestro glad it was helpful